# Git hook post-checkout for the first time

Tags: git

I found https://gist.github.com/wizioo/c89847c7894ede628071 very suitable for addressing my multiple branches with multiple gitignore.

There is still one thing to get it work, how to trigger post-checkout in the initial commit. It does works from the second checkout command after you already push the first commit to the repo.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see some weird behaviors when using multiple branches with multiple git ignore. Hence, now I am going to use a batch file to push multiple git repo with multiple git ignore.
Thanks.